# Need help to understand a step in the proof of Gaschütz’s Theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

In *The Theory of Finite Groups*, by Kurzweil & Stellmacher, there is a proof of Gaschütz’s Theorem, which states the existence of a complement in $G$ for an abelian normal subgroup $K$, provided that $K$ has a complement in $U$, where $K\leqslant U\leqslant G$ and $\gcd(|K|,|G:U|)=1$.

There are too many details as to repeat them here, so I will only mention the part that is relevant to my question. Someone willing to help would want to read more from the book.

Given two transversals $S$ and $R$ for $U$, if they happen to be included in $S_0K$ for a third transversal $S_0$ of $U$, the proof introduces the notation
$$
  S|R = \prod_{s\sim r}sr^{-1},\tag{*}
$$
where the relation $\sim$ is defined in $S\times R$ by $s\sim r\iff sr^{-1}\in K$. Then, a number of 6 properties are verified, of which the third one I'm unable to show:
$$
  kS|R = k^{|G:K|}(S|R)\quad\text{for }k\in K.\tag3
$$
What I don't understand is the exponent of $k$ in the expression above. It's clear to me that the product defined in $(*)$ has $|G:U|$ factors because for each $s\in S$ there is exactly one $r\in R$ such that $sU=rU$ ($S$ and $R$ are transversals for $U$) and it can be shown that the condition $S,R\subseteq S_0K$ implies $sK=rK$.

So my question is how can I see that $(3)$ holds true? Furthermore, if $A$ is a complement of $K$ in $U$ (and my argument above is valid) then $(3)$ is equivalent to $k^{|A|-1}=1$ for all $k\in K$ because $\gcd(|K|,|G:U|)=1$.

(Also note that this theorem is used in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1525723/269050) to solve Exercise 4.)

---

**Edit:** for a self-contained proof of the theorem see https://hal.science/hal-04447918.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a probably a mistake, and it should be $k^{|G:U|}$ rather than $k^{|G:K|}$. Then the fact that $|G:U|$ is coprime to $|K|$ means that $k \mapsto k^{|G:U|}$ defines an automorphism of $K$, which is what you need for the proof to work.

Comment: Oh! My bad, you are right! Thank you for checking this out.

Comment: I've written all the details to make sure everything was clear. Here is the manuscript https://hal.science/hal-04447918.